# How to get length of a vimeo video?

Tags: php, javascript, vimeo

I am having a big problem. Problem is how to get the time duration of vimeo video? Here is the scenario.

> I have a input field in this field say i enter youtube url now i want
>   to put a validation that video should only be of 1 min, if yes then i
>   store this in database else i show an error message.

is it possible to do this thing for vimeo video files?

Answer (score 5):

**Usage**

```
echo vimeoVideoDuration('https://vimeo.com/115134273');
// output: 63 (video duration in seconds)
```

**Function**

```
/**
* Vimeo video duration in seconds
*
* @param $video_url
* @return integer|null Duration in seconds or null on error
*/
function vimeoVideoDuration($video_url) {

   $video_id = (int)substr(parse_url($video_url, PHP_URL_PATH), 1);

   $json_url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' . $video_id . '.xml';

   $ch = curl_init($json_url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $data = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

   if (!isset($data->video->duration)) {
       return null;
   }

   $duration = $data->video->duration;

   return $duration; // in seconds
}
```

Comment: this only works with public videos and now vimeo has a new api to use

Answer (score 3):

Vimeo now has a new API, check here:
[vimeo api](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start)

and all you need is :
1. create a app under your vimeo account here https://developer.vimeo.com/apps
2. get your client_id, client_secret, client_token of your vimeo app;
3. use one of those official lib(php, python, node): https://github.com/vimeo

it is very easy but don't forget to optimise our API call as here says because vimeo api has a rate limit:
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/common-formats#json-filter

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as a matter of fact its in their `Simple API`

http://vimeo.com/api/docs/simple-api

> **duration** Duration of the video in seconds

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the video, you might have to authenticate.
Here is a code I've made:

```
public function getVimeoVideoDuration($vimeoId)
    {
        $authorization = 'myaccesstoken';
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{$vimeoId}",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "authorization: Bearer {$authorization}",
                "cache-control: no-cache",
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);

        curl_close($curl);
        if (empty($err)) {
            $info = json_decode($response);
            if(isset($info->duration)){
                return (int)$info->duration;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The authorization code can be requested [here](https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/78327#authentication).

Answer (score 0):

```
function vimeoVideoDuration($video_url) {

$video_id = (int)substr(parse_url($video_url, PHP_URL_PATH), 1);

$json_url = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/video/' . $video_id . '.xml';

$ch = curl_init($json_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = new SimpleXmlElement($data, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

if (!isset($data->video->duration)) {
    return null;
}

$duration = $data->video->duration;
return $duration; 
} 

echo vimeoVideoDuration('https://vimeo.com/547217109');
```

// return in seconds